# Can't boot ubuntu from flash drive "System has no USB option"

Tags: boot, usb, uefi, acer, aspire

Hi I've been trying for hours to boot Ubuntu and was wondering if I could get help with this.

Things I've tried:

Putting flash drive at the top of the boot list in BIOS

Turning secure boot off

Loading in Legacy

Going to the boot menu via f12, where the USB drive doesn't even appear in UEFI and appears but gives an error in legacy, says something like "system has no USB option" in UEFI

-

I have an Acer Aspire VX15 and Windows 10, I burned the ubuntu 16.10 iso to the USB drive via the 'ISO to USB' program

Thanks

Comment: 16.10 is obsolete. Please use a current version 18.04 or 16.04 which also are LTS or long term support. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot Most brands are very similar across models. And all Acer once install require you to enable "trust" to boot the ubuntu .efi boot files.